# Pass selected dataTable row to another dataTable row in another php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, sqlsrv

I have these two tables, namely table1.php and table2.php

I can pass the data to a modal using this script, this script is in table1.php, and it can pass data into table2.php via modal, my concern now is how will I pass the data directly into table2.php's SQL Query? Because of the way that it is, I can only use the data passed into a modal for HTML elements. Is there a way to pass the modal value and convert it into a SQL Query for PHP?

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on('click', '.edit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#edit').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
  });
```

I'm trying to pass the selected data row into another PHP page so that it will become the parameter for filtering the second PHP table.

This is my **table1.php**

```
<form type="POST" action="table2.php">
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Series No.</th>
                  <th>Account Type</th>
                  <th>Tools</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounttype";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                          <td>
                            <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              </form>
```

And this will be my **table2.php**

```
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Series No.</th>
                  <th>Account Type</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                    $id=$_POST['seriesno'];
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounttype where seriesno='$id'";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

The problem is that **table2.php** cannot receive the **$_POST**, what seems to be the problem here?

EDIT: This is my modal (**table2.php**) What I need is for the data to be passed into the table so that `$id=$_POST['seriesno'];` will work.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" class="decid" id="id" name="id">

  <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Series No.</th>
                  <th>Account Type</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                    $id=$_POST['seriesno'];
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounttype where seriesno='$id'";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you posting to table2?

Comment: @MoisheSchwartz ````$id=$_POST['seriesno'];````, I'm trying to pass the selected dataTable value to table2.php

Comment: @pjustindaryll, the commenter above me asking where is the form where you trying to submit your data to another .php script? show your modal html.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Apologies, I'm trying to submit it to another .php page.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I can pass the data to a modal using the script, this script is in table1.php, and it can pass data into table2.php via modal, my concern now is how will I pass the data directly into table2.php's SQL Query instead of passing it via modal?

Comment: So have you resolved you issue?

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco, nope, I haven't, I need the data to be passed into an SQL Query, what I have right now is that the data can only be passed into an html element. I can't find a way to use the data and convert it into a SQL query filter.

Comment: show your modal script and html

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I edited my post. Please check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. the problem is that you have to submit on the same page: and parse the `$_POST` array in modal window in the same page because it it included here.
Try this:

table1.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="table1.php">
          <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <th>Series No.</th>
              <th>Account Type</th>
              <th>Tools</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounttype";
                $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                  echo "
                    <tr>
                    <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                      <td>
                        <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>
                        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ";
                }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </form>
```

table2.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" class="decid" id="id" name="id">

  <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Series No.</th>
                  <th>Account Type</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['seriesno'])){
                    $id=$_POST['seriesno'];
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounttype where seriesno='$id'";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }
                    }

                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it heps

Comment: It didn't work. The data is from Table1, and then passed to Table2.

Comment: post your `table2.php` pls

Comment: It's posted. my modal and datatable is inside table2.php

Comment: I reread your entire post and have a question: HOW have you organized your code? Why jquery script which calls modal is in table1.php and why your modal is located in table2.php? are they both included in one index.php? or how you organized your files?

Comment: apologies, my jquery script is located in table1. and then table2 is being added as ````include()```` in the main page.

Comment: Also i would suggest you to use `table2.php` like separate file and use `jquery` to call this file on time when modal window shows, the modal html can be included in `table1.php`, you just return `JSON` array to `ajax` call and render them like you like.